# Paramterizing a walk from $(R, \phi, \theta)=(a,\pi /2, 0)$ to the North Pole, walking North-West

Tags: parametric, spherical-geometry

Assuming that the earth is a perfect sphere with radius a, we start our journey in the point $(R, \phi, \theta) = (a, \pi/2, 0)$ (Spherical coordinates) and we travel North-West with constant speed v.

I want to find the function $\phi(t)$ and $\theta(t)$ that describe the path. The question at first is, why for $\phi(t)$ the differential equation

$$a \frac{d\phi}{dt} = -\frac{v}{\sqrt2}$$ holds.

Understanding this should give information to set up a differential equation for $\theta(t)$.

The problem is that I don't understand the differential equation that holds for $\phi(t)$, I thought it might have something to do with the fact that $sin(\frac{\pi}{4}) = cos(\frac{\pi}{4})=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$.
Solving it, I find $\phi(t) = \frac{-v}{a\sqrt2}t+C$ and because we have the starting point $(a, \pi/2,0)$, we see that $C = \pi/2$.

How should I read the differential equation for $\phi(t)$ and how can I set up one for $\theta(t)$?

Comment: I found that the direction vector of the speed makes angle $\pi/4$ with the z-axis, so the horizontal speed has direction vector $v/\sqrt2$. But why should this be divided by a?

Comment: There are (at least) two different conventions for the meaning of $\phi$ and $\theta$. See, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system. In this problem the North Pole seems to correspond with $\phi=0$. The division by $a$ transforms the velocity in length units per time unit to radians per time unit.

Comment: That makes sense! But from that perspective, how can I find a differential equation for $\theta(t)$?

Comment: The velocity in western direction equals that in the northern direction, but is along a circle of latitude with radius $a \sin \theta$, which leads to a different angular velocity.

Comment: Why a circle with radius $a sin(\theta)$? That whould mean that for t=0 we have a circle with radius $a sin(0) = 0$, but we have a circle with radius $a$ then.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. It should have been $a \sin\phi$.

Comment: Does that mean that for $\theta(t)$ we can say that $\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\frac{v}{asin(\phi)\sqrt2}$? So that $\theta(t) = \frac{vt}{asin(\phi)\sqrt2} + C$ with C=0 because of $\theta(0)=0$?

Comment: I mean $\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\frac{-v}{asin(\phi)\sqrt2}$ and $\theta(t) = \frac{-vt}{asin(\phi)\sqrt2}$ because we walk clockwise toward North-West

Comment: The integral is a bit tricky because $\sin \phi$ depends on $t$.